# Clarify Ingress load balancer

Tags: kubernetes

I'm not sure how load balancing works with Ingress.
If I understand correctly, what happens is actually something like this:

[image]

I fail to see how the load balancing is performed.
What is wrong in the above scheme that I have drawn?
Can you help me rectify it?

Notes:
- The following answer tells me that the Ingress controller itself is of type 'loadbalancer': [Ingress service type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959974/ingress-service-type)
- I use kind ClusterIP because I don't want to expose the loadbalancer to the outside world. The following article does not support this claim, where the load balancer would be provided by the service:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0

[image]

Comment: Is it clear that the ingress controller is itself a Pod/s? happy to chat about this - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186559/room-for-ryan-dawson-and-trace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ClusterIP` services themselves perform load balancing. The naming can be confusing as `LoadBalancer` services are not the only services that involve load balancing - `LoadBalancer` actually means something more like 'cloud provider please create an external load balancer and point it at this service'. The kubernetes `ClusterIP` services also [load-balance across Pods in different Nodes using the kube-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49892871/9705485). If you don't want kubernetes to do load balancing then you have to specifically disable it by [creating a headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services).

Comment: Worth noting in this context that if you do want load balancing but for external traffic to stay within the node it landed at then you can set externalTrafficPolicy - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the first scheme you drew is correct. But I think you get confused in terminology. Particularly in the difference between `ingress` and `ingress-controller`.

`Ingress` is a type of resources in k8s (like `Service`, `Deployment`, `ReplicaSet` etc). We use ingress if we want to expose some services to an external world with binding to some path and host (i.e. myapp.com/api -> my-api-service).

The job of `ingress-controller` is to handle creation/update/deletion of ingress resources and implement all the functionality needed for ingress. Under the hood ingress-controller is a simple deployment exposed as `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort` service depending on where k8s is deployed. And ingress-controller forwards received request further to one of pods of service which matches host and path in some of the deployed ingress resources.

Answer (score 1):

I got curious and thought: why would I need an Ingress for load balancing on layer 7 if the only thing it does is forward the traffic to a Service that implements the load balancing on layer 4?

Most Ingress controller implementations I looked up, talk to the Kubernetes API server to keep track of all Pods associated with a Service. Instead of forwarding traffic to the Service, they skip the intermediary and directly forward to the Pods. Since an ingress controller operates on layer 7, it enables a more application-oriented load balancing.