# is clusterIP accessible from other node?

Tags: kubernetes

i saw some statement that clusterIP can not be accessed by external machine outside the cluster.

but i am not sure what the cluster mean here, does it mean cluster of pods or cluster of nodes.

ultimate question, can clusterIP (without node port) be accessed by other nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ClusterIP services can be reached by nodes in the cluster. Part of their purpose is to load-balance across replicas for Pods (which may be in different Nodes) so that traffic isn't all going to particular Pods. See [Clarify Ingress load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150887/clarify-ingress-load-balancer)

A ClusterIP service doesn't really live on any single Node but rather on each Node. The kube-proxy on each Node ensures that the load-balancing across instances takes place by updating each Nodes iptables

Comment: if we put external load balancer into d picture, so there will be 2 times load balancing process? first one in the LB, then second one at the kube-proxy? Assuming we use the nodePort. thx in advance.

Comment: Yes but for different purposes. The Service load-balances across Pods. The external load balancer would load balance across Nodes. There could be an uneven distribution of Pods across Nodes. Then just load balancing by Node will be unfair on some Pods. So by by default k8s Services will try to ensure each Pod still gets its fair share. But if you don't want the double load-balancing then you can keep traffic internal to the Node using externalTrafficPolicy - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip

Comment: A good way to think of it is that an external load balancer load balances external entry into the cluster. The Services then load balance across Pods that are replicas of one another within the cluster. If the Pods mostly happen to be on the same node then they still get an even share (at least with the default behaviour).