# Load balancing on same server

Tags: networking, server, kubernetes

I research about Kubernetes and actually saw that they do load balancer on a same node. So if I'm not wrong, one node means one server machine, so what good it be if doing load balancer on the same server machine. Because it will use same CPU and RAM to handle requests. First I thought that load balancing would do on separate machine to share resource of CPU and RAM. So I wanna know the point of doing load balancing on same server.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it on one node , it doesn't mean that you should do it , specially in production environment.

- the production cluster will have least 3 or 5 nodes min
- kubernetes will spread the replicas across the cluster nodes in balancing node workload , pods ends up on different nodes
- you can also configure on which nodes your pods land
- use advanced scheduling , pod affinity and anti-affinity
- you can also plug you own schedular , that will not allow placing the replica  pods of the same app on the same node
- then you define a service to loadbalance across pods on different nodes
- kube proxy will do the rest

here is a useful read:

https://itnext.io/keep-you-kubernetes-cluster-balanced-the-secret-to-high-availability-17edf60d9cb7

> So you generally need to choose a level of availability you are
>   comfortable with. For example, if you are running three nodes in three
>   separate availability zones, you may choose to be resilient to a
>   single node failure. Losing two nodes might bring your application
>   down but the odds of loosing two data centres in separate availability
>   zones are low.
>
> The bottom line is that there is no universal approach; only you can
>   know what works for your business and the level of risk you deem
>   acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean how Services do automatical load-balancing. Imagine you have a Deployment with 2 replicas on your one node and a Service. Traffic to the Pods goes through the Service so if that were not load-balancing then everything would go to just one Pod and the other Pod would get nothing. You could then handle more load by spreading evenly and still be confident that traffic will be served if one Pod dies.

You can also load-balance traffic coming into the cluster from outside so that the entrypoint to the cluster isn't always the same node. But that is a different level of load-balancing. Even with one node you can still want load-balancing for the Services within the cluster. See [Clarify Ingress load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150887/clarify-ingress-load-balancer) on load-balancing of external entrypoint.

Comment: Thanks for clarify me, So the point of doing load balance on one node is protect a service downing when one services down another service will be instead of.  So it cannot handle more requests of the service. because it uses the same cpu and ram on the same machine. it only help protect server from down or interrupt. do I understand correctly?

Comment: You could scale vertically and give all the CPU and ram to the one Pod. Though it could fail for reasons other than resource limits so you might want to avoid a single point of failure. It may have a memory leak or a subtle bug. Kubernetes is about horizontal scaling through replicas. It is a container orchestrator. Within it each Pod gets a certain isolation and its own min and max allocations of CPU and ram. But in practice orchestration is about having lots of containers. If you really just wanted to run one container on one server then you wouldn't benefit from k8s

Comment: thank you for your kindness. I assume that if a machine can handle 1000 requests. if I run 2 same containers. each container can handle 500 requests. but if I run one containers it can handle 1000 requests. do I understand correctly?. the benefit of separation is if one down another container can still handle requests. So I wanna know that Normally we should run pods or replicas on different node if we want to do load balance with horizontal scaling

Comment: Yes normally you want to have multiple nodes and to spread the Pods of the same type around the nodes to avoid single points of failure. That is what Ijaz Ahmad Khan is explaining in his answer