# Load Balancing between PODS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

Is there a way to do active and passive load balancing between 2 PODs of a micro-service. Say I have 2 instance(PODs) running of Micro-service, which is exposed using a K8s service object. Is there a way to configure the load balancing such a way that one pod will always get the request and when that pod is down , the other pod will start receiving the request?

I have ingress object also on top of that service.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the Kubernetes Service object does, which you already mentioned you are using. Make sure you set up a readiness probe in your pod template so that the system can tell when your app is healthy.

Comment: Pod need `livenessProbe` along with readiness to fully satisfy the requirement.Also the load-balancing algorithm is depends on the mode of [proxy]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888133/kubernetes-service-cluster-ip-how-is-this-internally-load-balanced-across-diffe)

Comment: That is incorrect, liveness probes are unrelated and matter for pod tear down and crash detection, they are only needed with software that can lock up without crashing. They are useful but not involved in balancing.

Comment: "only needed with software that can lock up without crashing" ...so always? :)

Comment: You have to weigh the benefits against the risks of false positives which can do more harm than good at times :) A bad liveness probe can destabilize things a lot more than a flaky readiness probe.

Comment: @coderanger yes I am using Service which will do a round robin/random load balancing between the pods. My question was, can we configure that load balancing method. Like instead of round robin , only one pod will get the request always , and other pod will be sitting there and if that pod goes down then it will start taking the request.

Comment: I don’t think that is one of the options, but you can look up the IPVS scheduler options and check. Might be able to write it yourself in BPF, but this is kind of silly and now how K8s is supposed to be used.